# How to do a WP_User_Query in Wordpress 3.0.1?

Tags: list-authors

How do I query a list of authors / users in Wordpress 3.0.1?

I'd upgrade but my theme doesn't support WP 3.2.1

Comment: Frankly, you should upgrade the theme to support WP 3.2.  Particularly if you're trying to use an object (`WP_User_Query`) that was introduced in a *later* version of WordPress (it doesn't exist in 3.0.1!).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `WP_User_Query` class with 3.1 and higher, there was `WP_User_Search` class which is deprecated since 3.1, also see this article from Steve Taylor you may find it helpful - http://sltaylor.co.uk/blog/get-wordpress-users-by-role/